# Swift Framework - public class results as undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift

I've written a custom framework in swift. This framework has a lot of classes... and all these classes have been marked as public.

```
public class Person{ 
...
}
```

When I import my framework into another project I would expect to be able to use the `Person` class since it has been marked as public but I'm actually getting an error message saying that Person is an undeclared type.

These are the steps that I follow to include the framework into my project:

1. Drag framework into the project in Xcode
2. Add the framework to embedded binaries and to Link binaries with Libraries if is not there already
3. import the framework where I need to use it with `import MYFramework`

Am I missing anything?!

Answer (score 1):

You should add public init method

```
    public init() { }
```